# How can I transform database from sql server 2005 to 2000

Tags: sql-server-2005

how can I transform database from sql server 2005 to 2000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that you aren't using any native 2005 features like included columns on indexes, XML features, etc.  Then you can script the schema out using SSMS, and export the data using BCP or SSIS to SQL 2000.  Some vendor tools exist like RedGate SQL Compare and Data Compare that make doing this a whole lot easier if you have primary keys defined on your tables.

Answer (score 1):

Use SSIS to export the database directly to SQL Server 2000.